# c3 spline chart - Multiple Data on Multiple y Axes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, c3.js

How can I bind [data1, data2 and data3] to y axis and data4 to y2 axis? 
Here is my actual solution: https://codepen.io/luko248/pen/wvaeYON.

Comment: Please try to show some code and error examples in your question rather than requiring people to visit an external site. Some explanation of what you have already tried would also help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the y2 axis data within your data parameters:

```
data: { 
    axes: {data4: 'y2'} 
}
```

Have a look at the C3 documentation under Customize Chart: 1. Additional Axis https://c3js.org/gettingstarted.html#customize

I have made a JSFiddle based on your code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/89pfy1k4/2/

Below the embedded JS snipped:

```js
 var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#PowerChart',
       
        data: {
            x: 'DateTime',
            xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', //%Y-%m-%d
            columns: [
                ['DateTime', '2019-01-02 00:00:00', '2019-01-02 00:10:00', '2019-01-02 00:20:00', '2019-01-02 00:30:00', '2019-01-02 00:40:00', '2019-01-02 00:50:00', '2019-01-02 01:00:00',
                    '2019-01-02 01:10:00', '2019-01-02 01:20:00'],
                ['data1', 30, 20, 10, 15, 35, 16, 18, 42],
                ['data2', 120, 110, 98, 45, 87, 56, 72, 32],
                ['data3', 80, 75, 95, 105, 120, 40, 35, 68],
                ['data4', 40, 45, 40, 45, 50, 40, 45, 50],
            ],
            names: {
                data1: 'PV Power(W)',
                data2: 'Grid(W)',
                data3: 'Battery(W)',
                data4: 'SOC(%)',
            },
            colors: {
                data1: '#be1b19',
                data2: '#ff9c38',
                data3: '#06ac4e',
                data4: 'purple',
            },
            axes: { data4: 'y2'},
            type: `spline`
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                tick: {
                    format: '%H:%M',
                }
            },
            y: {
                tick: {
                    format: function (d) { return d + "(W)"; }
                }
            },
            y2: {
                show: true,
                tick: {
                    format: function (d) { return d + "(%)"; }
                }
            }
        },
        point: {
            r: 0,
            focus: {
                expand: {
                    r: 4
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'inset',
            inset: {
                anchor: 'bottom-right',
                x: -30,
                y: -75,
                step: 1
            }
        },
        padding: {
            bottom: 15,
            left: 25,
            right: 35
        },
        grid: {
            x: {
                show: true
            },
            y: {
                show: true
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
.chart__container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;

    .c3-tooltip-container {
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .3);
    }

    .c3-axis {
        fill: black;
    }

    .domain {
        stroke: black;
    }

    .c3-chart-arc text {
        font-size: small;
    }

    .c3-legend-background {
        stroke-width: 0;
    }

    .c3-grid line {
        stroke: #eaeaea;
        stroke-dasharray: 0;
    }

    .c3-tooltip {
        border: none;

        tbody {

            th {
                background-color: black;

                &:first-of-type {
                    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
                }

                &:last-of-type {
                    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
                }
            }

            td {
                border-color: hsl(0, 0%, 84%);
            }

            > tr:last-of-type > td {

                &:first-of-type {
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
                }

                &:last-of-type {
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.15/c3.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div id="PowerChart" class="chart__container"></div>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.15/c3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```